# How refactor switch in javascript for cleaner code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, refactoring

I am trying to write some cleaner Javascript / jQuery code. How do I refactor this function into something cleaner and smaller. Definitely seems like there is a better way to do this. It works but i'm sure there is a better way of getting writing a function like this. Thanks in advance!

```
function filterForm(purpose, entry) {
    switch (purpose) {
        case 'Business' : 
            switch (entry) {
                case 'Single': 
                    $("#moreq1").css( "display", "block" );   
                    $("#moreq2").css( "display", "none"  );   
                    $("#moreq3").css( "display", "none"  );  

                    break;
                case 'Double': 
                    $("#moreq1").css( "display", "block" );   
                    $("#moreq2").css( "display", "none"  );   
                    $("#moreq3").css( "display", "none"  );  

                    break;
                case 'Multiple' : 
                    $("#moreq1").css( "display", "block" );   
                    $("#moreq2").css( "display", "block" );   
                    $("#moreq3").css( "display", "none"  );  

                    break;
                }

                break;
            case 'Private' : 
                switch (entry) {
                    case 'Single'   : 
                        $("#moreq1").css( "display", "block" );   
                        $("#moreq2").css( "display", "none"  );   
                        $("#moreq3").css( "display", "none"  );  

                        break;
                    case 'Double'   : 
                        $("#moreq1").css( "display", "none"  );   
                        $("#moreq2").css( "display", "none"  );   
                        $("#moreq3").css( "display", "none"  );  

                        break;
                    case 'Multiple' : 
                        $("#moreq1").css( "display", "none"  );   
                        $("#moreq2").css( "display", "none"  );   
                       $("#moreq3").css( "display", "none"  );  

                        break;
                }   

                break;
            case 'Tourist' : 
                switch (entry) {
                    case 'Single'   : 
                        $("#moreq1").css( "display", "block" );   
                        $("#moreq2").css( "display", "none"  );   
                        $("#moreq3").css( "display", "block"  );  

                        break;
                    case 'Double'   : 
                        $("#moreq1").css( "display", "none" );   
                        $("#moreq2").css( "display", "none"  );   
                        $("#moreq3").css( "display", "none"  );  

                        break;
                    case 'Multiple' : 
                        $("#moreq1").css( "display", "none"  );   
                        $("#moreq2").css( "display", "none" );   
                        $("#moreq3").css( "display", "none" );  

                        break;
                }       

                break;
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the other answers have done a decent job of combining the possibilities, it seems more logical to me to use a "map" of all the possibilities, and reference that:

```
var filterForm = (function () {
    var moreq = [
        "",        // So you can use indexes starting at 1
        "moreq1",
        "moreq2",
        "moreq3"
    ], Purposes = {
        "Business": {
            "Single": [moreq[1]],
            "Double": [moreq[1]],
            "Multiple": [moreq[1], moreq[2]]
        },
        "Private": {
            "Single": [moreq[1]],
            "Double": [],
            "Multiple": []
        },
        "Tourist": {
            "Single": [moreq[1], moreq[],
            "Double": [],
            "Multiple": []
        }
    };

    return function (purpose, entry) {
        var i, j, cur, display;

        for (i = 1, j = moreq.length; i < j; i++) {
            cur = moreq[i];
            display = Purposes[purpose][entry].indexOf(cur) > -1 ? "block" : "none";
            console.log("Setting " + cur + " as " + display);
            //$("#" + cur).css("display", display);
        }
    };
}());

filterForm("Business", "Multiple");
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/w3Jnn/1/

The arrays in the object are which elements to set the display as `block`. As soon as you want to change a specific setting, just modify the `Purposes` object's arrays.

And of course, my function doesn't do much checking the `Purposes[purpose][entry].indexOf(cur) > -1` part - it assumes the `purpose` and `entry` parameters will have valid values. This could be modified to check, but it didn't seem important right now.

As a note, this uses a closure (the surrounding `(function () { })`) to instantiate the `Purposes` and `items` variables once, yet keep them out of the global scope.

Also note, the `Array.indexOf` method isn't supported in all browsers (mainly old IE), so there's a shim at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility to include on your page to make sure it works, among other ones you can find with Google.

Comment: Thank you very much. Amazing, learnt so much from one function :)

Comment: +1 Nice, have a look at my answer for an easier (shorter) mapping system :-)

Comment: @Bergi Yeah I literally just saw your edit; I like that too :) I just like to be more explicit and/or start from the top. Clearly either approach would work fine :)

Comment: @londonjava I updated my answer with minor changes, but might help with readability; I changed the `items` array at the beginning to be `moreq` and then referenced that in the object's arrays.

Comment: @dandavis Thanks :) Bergi has another mapping option that might be better, but either way the approach is better than nested `switch`/`if`

Answer (score 1):

After looking at all your conditions, it seems to boil down to this:

```
function filterForm(purpose, entry) {
    var q1 = purpose == 'Business' || entry == 'Single' ? 'block' : 'none';
    var q2 = purpose == 'Business' && entry == 'Multiple' ? 'block' : 'none';
    var q3 = purpose == 'Tourist' && entry == 'Single' ? 'block' : 'none';

    $("#moreq1").css( "display", q1 );   
    $("#moreq2").css( "display", q2 );   
    $("#moreq3").css( "display", q3 ); 
}
```

Comment: I can see the logic in this but purpose can theoretically be either "Business", "Private" and "Tourist". This only takes into account one journey.

Comment: @londonjava Ooops right, I screwed up. But you get the idea: identify common patterns, and try to replace them with a few simple if statements.

Comment: @londonjava One thing that should help: create 3 tables (q1, q2 and q3) to see the values for all the possible combinations. It will be easier to create the conditionals based on that.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with removing all hiding statements - just hide all in general and then show only those that need to (here with `if`-statements, see [@nmynarcik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17707208/1048572) for an intermediate step with `switch`es):

```
function filterForm(purpose, entry) {
    $("#moreq1, #moreq2, #moreq3").css("display", "none");

    if (purpose == 'Business') {
        $("#moreq1").css("display", "block");
        if (entry == 'Multiple')
            $("#moreq2").css("display", "block");
    } else if (purpose == 'Private' && entry == 'Single')
         $("#moreq1").css("display", "block");
    } else if (purpose == 'Tourist' && entry == 'Single') {
         $("#moreq1, #moreq3").css("display", "block");
    }
}
```

which could be further simplified to

```
function filterForm(purpose, entry) {
    $("#moreq1, #moreq2, #moreq3").css("display", "none");

    if (purpose == 'Business' || entry == 'Single')
         $("#moreq1").css("display", "block");
    if (purpose == 'Business' && entry == 'Multiple')
         $("#moreq2").css("display", "block");
    if (purpose == 'Tourist' && entry == 'Single')
         $("#moreq3").css("display", "block");
}
```

If it's getting more complicated I'd recommend a lookup map for the single display values, instead of using a `switch` statement with much repeated statements. For your setup it would look like

```
var show = {
    "moreq1": {
        "Business": true,
        "Private": {
            "Single": true
        },
        "Tourist": {
            "Single": true
        }
    },
    "moreq2": {
        "Business": {
            "Multiple": true
        }
    },
    "moreq3": {
        "Tourist": {
             "Single": true
        }
    }
};
for (var id in show) {
    var l = show[id];
    $("#"+id).css("display", l[purpose] === true || l[purpose] && l[purpose][entry] ? "block" : "none");
}
```

Of course you could swap the order of `purpose` and `entry` if that gets shorter.

Comment: Just studied this (last section) also a very clear and nice solution. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how much I like this way but this is a non-switch, non-if way of doing it. It can also help for testing as well since you could unit test *lookup* independently.

However, if *purpose* or *entry* aren't keys in *lookup* then you'll get some errors thrown.

```
function filterForm(purpose, entry) {
    var lookup = {}
    lookup['Business'] = {'Single':{'q1':'block','q2':'none','q3':'none'},
                         {'Double':{'q1':'block','q2':'none','q3':'none'}};

    lookup['Private'] = {...etc...};

    $('#moreq1').css('display', lookup[purpose][entry]['q1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick to using switched, give them all a class and you can set all to display: none; when you start your method.

Then doing:

```
function filterForm(purpose, entry) {

   $('.qItem').hide();

    switch (purpose) {

        case 'Business' : 

            $("#moreq1").css( "display", "block" );

            switch (entry) {

                case 'Multiple' : 

                    $("#moreq2").css( "display", "block" );

                break;

            }

        break;

        case 'Private' : 

            switch (entry) {

                case 'Single'   : 

                    $("#moreq1").css( "display", "block" );   
                    break;

            }   

        break;

        case 'Tourist' : 

            switch (entry) {

                case 'Single'   : 

                    $("#moreq1").css( "display", "block" );   
                    $("#moreq3").css( "display", "block"  );  

                break;

            }       

        break;

    }

}
```

You can see here how the class is used: http://jsfiddle.net/pMfgy/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function filterForm(purpose, entry) {
    var hideMap = {
        Business: {
            Single: [2, 3],
            Double: [2, 3],
            Multiple: [3]
        },
        Private: {
            Single: [2, 3],
            Double: [1, 2, 3],
            Multiple: [1, 2, 3]
        },
        Tourist: {
            Single: [2],
            Double: [1, 2, 3],
            Multiple: [1, 2, 3]
        }
    };

    hideShow(hideMap[purpose][entry]);
}

function hideShow(a) {
    var allEls = '#moreq1, #moreq2, #moreq3';
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        a[i] = '#moreq' + a[i];
    }
    var hideEls = a.join(',');
    $(hideEls).hide(a.join());
    $(allEls).not(hideEls).show();
}
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/3LSdD/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

As many people have stated, it **looks** like you could simplify the display logic considerably, but if it is important to you to maintain the different states based on the of the `moreq1`, `moreq2`, and`moreq3` elements, based on the `purpose` and `entry` variable values, then I would suggest that you shift the bulk of the display "logic" over to CSS, instead of JS/jQuery . . .

Most of that logic can be replaced with CSS style definitions that are tied to the `purpose` and `entry` values:

**CSS**

```
// "Business" display styles
// "Business - Single" display styles
.business.single #moreq1 {display: block}
.business.single #moreq2,
.business.single #moreq3 {display: none}

// "Business - Double" display styles
.business.double #moreq1 {display: block}
.business.double #moreq2,
.business.double #moreq3 {display: none}

// "Business - Multiple" display styles
.business.multiple #moreq1,
.business.multiple #moreq2 {display: block}
.business.multiple #moreq3 {display: none}

// "Private" display styles
// "Private - Single" display styles
.private.single #moreq1 {display: block}
.private.single #moreq2,
.private.single #moreq3 {display: none}

// "Private - Double" display styles
.private.double #moreq1,
.private.double #moreq2,
.private.double #moreq3 {display: none}

// "Private - Multiple" display styles
.private.multiple #moreq1,
.private.multiple #moreq2,
.private.multiple #moreq3 {display: none}

// "Tourist" display styles
// "Tourist - Single" display styles
.tourist.single #moreq1,
.tourist.single #moreq3 {display: block}
.tourist.single #moreq2 {display: none}

// "Tourist - Double" display styles
.tourist.double #moreq1,
.tourist.double #moreq2,
.tourist.double #moreq3 {display: none}

// "Tourist - Multiple" display styles
.tourist.multiple #moreq1,
.tourist.multiple #moreq2,
.tourist.multiple #moreq3 {display: none}
```

After that, you can simple assign styles using jQuery to the parent container (or even the `<body>` tag), using the `purpose` and `entry` values:

**JS**

```
function filterForm(purpose, entry) {
    var dynamicClasses = purpose + " " + entry;
    $("#parent_element_ID").addClass(dynamicClasses.toLowerCase());
}
```

At that point, the CSS will take over and show/display the elements based on your CSS rules.

While it may seem like a lot of CSS, not only does it use CSS for it's intended purpose, but it also makes any changes (or additions of new sections), a simple CSS update, rather than a JS code change.